# Mock Jest Function Instance Doesn't Carry Over to Call in Other File

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, instance

Mock Jest function instance doesn't seem to carry over to an imported module. I have a function `sendDataHandler` that calls `sendToEH`. I want to write jest test that makes sure calls to `sendDataHandler` make calls to `sendToEH`.

So my implementation:

```js
app.sendToEH = jest.fn();

await app.sendDataHandler(req, res, next);

expect(app.sendToEH).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This test fails. When I go into debug mode and follow the sequential operations, `sendDataHandler` calls `sendToEH` from the module instead of the defined mock function.

If I write:

```
app.sendToEH = jest.fn();

await app.sendToEH('asdf');

await app.sendDataHandler(req, res, next);

expect(app.sendToEH).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The test passes.

Why does the instance of the mock function not carry through to the other file/module? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642:

The first strategy you could use is storing the references to your methods in an object which you will then export. sendDataHandler will invoke the reference of sendToEH stored in that object.

module:

```
var sendToEH = function sendToEH() {};
var sendDataHandler = function sendDataHandler() { exportFunctions.sendToEH(); };
const exportFunctions = {
  sendToEH,
  sendDataHandler
};
export default exportFunctions;
```

test file:

```
app.exportFunctions.sendToEH = jest.fn();

await app.exportFunctions.sendDataHandler(req, res, next);

expect(app.exportFunctions.sendToEH).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In this way, you will import and mocking the same reference to sendToEH which is called by sendDataHandler() and the same test previously defined will now pass!